# Overview of using Grafana for automated sql reports?

Tags: automation, mysql, postgresql

I have a couple types of databases (postgres, mysql) that I regularly run queries on and email the reports. I want a reporting dashboard to automate these tasks. I've heard Grafana is a good way to go, but I'm open to other recommendations, especially if they're more cost-effective. Using Grafana, are there plug-ins or other software that's needed to automate the tasks?

Comment: Try, for instance: collectd, munin, icinga or nagios (in any order). They differ in implementation, number of dependencies, plugin availability, operating system availability, frontend look-and-feel.